# getting expected error in the code type error

Tags: python, excel, selenium, automation

```
file="item.xlsx"
rows=xlutil.getRowCount(file,"Sheet1")

for r in range(2,rows+1):

    hs=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 1)
    itemdesc=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1",r, 2)
    iscod=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 3)
    steel=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 4)     
    endus=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 5)
    imppur=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 6)
    coo=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 7)
    impqty=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 8)
    cif=xlutil.readData(file,"Sheet1", r, 9)

#passingdatatoappl

#status_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="hsCode"]'))
#status_select.select_by_visible_text(hs)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="itemDesc"]').send_keys(itemdesc)

icdrp=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="isCode"]'))
icdrp.select_by_visible_text(iscod)

sttype=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="steelType"]'))
sttype.select_by_visible_text(steel)

endapp=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="endUse"]'))
endapp.select_by_visible_text(endus)

purpose=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="importPurpose"]'))
purpose.select_by_visible_text(imppur)

origin=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="countryOrigin"]'))
origin.select_by_visible_text(coo)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="importQuantity"]').send_keys(impqty)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cifUSD"]').send_keys(cif)
```

Comment: I am getting a error expected type error in python - object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: expected type error in python - argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable